# Installing packages in conda environments fails when conda attempts to uninstall a root package

Tags: anaconda, conda

I've installed Anaconda on linux, it's installed in user space under my home folder.

I've created an environment.

Within that environment I've run `conda install anaconda` to install all standard packages.

I'm trying to install tensorflow now, running:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

This process attempts to upgrade the `numpy` package. But that step errors out because it's trying to uninstall the system numpy package in `/usr/local/bin/f2py`.

I thought this environment was all self-contained in user space. Any idea why it would attempt to uninstall a system package that was installed before Anaconda was installed?

Comment: Do you have `PYTHONPATH` set?

Comment: Ah, yes, I do, and by no coincidence I'm sure, it's pointing to the system python installation. I would expect Conda to handle details like this. Is that a bad expectation to have?

Comment: I see, clearing the PYTHONPATH environment variable solved the problem. @darthbith - you should post that as the answer and I'll accept it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, I think its a bad expectation to have that other software will go and change environment variables that you have set :-)

Comment: Don't you hate it when logic stands firmly in the way of what seems like perfectly harmless common sense?

Comment: Indeed, I often wish my computer did what I meant, not what I said :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to clear your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, if its pointing at the system installation of Python.